# Laravel Webpack - Unwanted minification of top level variable

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-elixir, rollupjs

I have a variable in my main javascript file e.g. `var example = {};`.

After webpack has finished its job, I find that `example` is now referenced as `t`. This presents me a problem as I am using the variable across the web project. I bind functions onto objects for example:

```
var example = {};
example.initialise = function () {};
```

Finally at the bottom of a page I may invoke this section of script e.g:

```
<script>example.initialise()</script>
```

This way of writing javascript functions is not unusual...

This is obviously a huge pain in the ass as I have no control over the minification. Moreover, it appears that webpack doesn't figure out that `example.initialise = function () {};` relates to its newly minified `var example (becoming)--> var t`. I.e. it doesn't become `t.initialise = function {};` either.

What am I supposed to do here?

I've tried using rollup as well. The same kind of variable minification happens.

The thing is, this kind of minification/obfuscation is great, particularly on the inner workings of functions where there's little cause for concern over the parameter names. But not on the top level. I do not understand why this is happening, or how to prevent it.

Any ideas?

I assume that there are ways to set the configuration of webpack. E.g. inside `webpack.config.js`, but my perusing of the webpack docs gives me no easy understanding of what options I can use to resolve this, like preventing property minification in some way.

Comment: Are you using UglifyJsPlugin with webpack?

Comment: @Bema how do I find out? I'm using [`laravel-elixir-webpack-official`](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-elixir-webpack-official)

Comment: Do you have a `webpack.config.js` file in your project?

Comment: @Bema I don't have one in the project, but AFAIU, it's not a requirement

Answer (score 1):

In laravel-elixir-webpack-official code you can see `minify()` is being applied [here](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-elixir-webpack-official/blob/master/src/WebpackTask.js#L46), `minify()` uses UglifyJS2 and mangling is on by default.

Mangling is an optimisation that reduces names of local variables and functions usually to single-letters (this explains your `example` object being renamed to `t`). [See the doc here.](http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/mangle)

I don't see any way you can customize `minify()` behaviour in laravel-elixir-webpack, so for now you might have to monkey patch `WebpackTask.prototype.gulpTask` method before using the module (not an ideal solution). See the lines I am commenting out.

```
const WebpackTask = require('laravel-elixir-webpack-official/dist/WebpackTask').default;

WebpackTask.prototype.gulpTask = function () {
    return (
        gulp
        .src(this.src.path)
        .pipe(this.webpack())
        .on('error', this.onError())
        // .pipe(jsFiles)
        // .pipe(this.minify()) 
        // .on('error', this.onError()) 
        // .pipe(jsFiles.restore)
        .pipe(this.saveAs(gulp))
        .pipe(this.onSuccess())
    );
};
```

Comment: Will check this out soon

Comment: An interesting idea, and well investigated Bema, thanks for your help on this. I've since resolved the issue however and will post a response on my simple solution!

Comment: Good catch @Jonathan , I didn't know top level maging was disable by default, just found this paragraph deep in UglifyJS docs: "mangle names in the toplevel scope too (by default we don’t do this)"

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I have been silly. I've discovered that you can prevent top level properties from being minified by binding it to `window`... which in hindsight is something I've always known and was stupid not to have realised sooner. D'oh!

So all that needed to be done was to change all top-level properties like `var example = {};` to something like `window.app.example = {};` in which `app` is helping to namespace and prevent and override anything set by the language itself.